# Image resizing issue on Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried following. It works on fiddle. But not work with html. Imgae get loaded but not resizing it while hoovering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var current_h = $('img').height();
var current_w = $('img').width();

        $('.resize').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: (current_w * 3.15),
                height: (current_h * 3.15)
            }, 300);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: current_w + 'px',
                height: current_h + 'px'
            }, 300);
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any issue in here ?

Comment: Try wrapping your function in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I do not see the reason why answers below should be marked down? All of them point to one very basic fact that the OP has tried to reference something that did not exists.

Comment: I marked one down that had the initialisation outside the function. It has now been fixed. The other one had no explanation

Comment: Anyone can tell me how I could take the zoomed image onto a separate window, when hovering the mouse on a thumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute onload - your code is run before the image exists:

```js
$(function() { // when the page has loaded
  var current_h = $('img').height();
  var current_w = $('img').width();

  $('.resize').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: (current_w * 3.15),
        height: (current_h * 3.15)
      }, 300);
    }, function() {
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: current_w + 'px',
        height: current_h + 'px'
      }, 300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250" />
</div>
```

If you have more than one image, you can save each image size in the img's data attribute - I also added the height to the image tag.

```js
$(function() { // when the page has loaded
  $(".box img").each(function() {
    $(this).data("w",$(this).width());
    $(this).data("h",$(this).height());
  });
  $('.resize').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: ($(this).data("w") * 3.15),
        height: ($(this).data("h") * 3.15)
      }, 300);
    }, function() {
      $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: $(this).data("w") + 'px',
        height: $(this).data("h") + 'px'
      }, 300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250" height="250" />
</div><div class="box">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250" height="250" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this. Works well on IE, but on Chrome sometimes it works, but most of the time it's "shrinks" the image and disappears.

Comment: That is not true if you do it right, the initial current size has to be taken after the image loads. Your code assumes ONE image in the page.I have no issues with my code in chrome.

Comment: Have a look at the changed example. I save the image size in the data attribute and added the height to the image tag too

Comment: Can guide me how I could take zoomed image onto a separate window, when hovering the mouse on a thumb. And hide that window once I move mouse out.

Comment: Ask a new question or just search the net for lightbox

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your function in `$(document).ready()`. Because your code is running before the image being loaded.

Below is an working example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var current_h = $('img').height();
      var current_w = $('img').width();
      $('.resize').hover(
        function() {
          $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: (current_w * 3.15),
            height: (current_h * 3.15)
          }, 300);
        }, function() {
          $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            width: current_w + 'px',
            height: current_h + 'px'
          }, 300);
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan : Thanks. Updated the answer!

Comment: Which is now identical to mine, including the comment

Comment: I have tried this. Works well on IE, but on Chrome sometimes it works, but most of the time it's "shrinks" the image and disappears.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var current_h = $('img').height();
var current_w = $('img').width();

        $('.resize').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: (current_w * 3.15),
                height: (current_h * 3.15)
            }, 300);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: current_w + 'px',
                height: current_h + 'px'
            }, 300);
        });
  
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ // Note this line
var current_h = $('img').height();
var current_w = $('img').width();

        $('.resize').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: (current_w * 3.15),
                height: (current_h * 3.15)
            }, 300);
        }, function () {
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: current_w + 'px',
                height: current_h + 'px'
            }, 300);
        });
        }); // note that the additional line ends here
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also please refer Jquery documentation on **$(document).ready**

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250"
```

to

```
img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" class="resize" width="250" height="250"
```

I think this would resolve your issues.

Thanks